# Network issue with VM-Fusion and fresh W7 on mac

Tags: windows-7, networking, vmware-fusion

In order to use VS-2015 I installed a fresh `Win-7 N x64 SP1` virtual machine on my Macbook Pro 2011.

It works like a charm, I was able to download the latest version of Firefox, the VS installer. Then I ran the installer which failed due to an unknown error.

`Windows Update` doesn't find any update and `Microsoft Fix It` isn't able to self download.

A few more informations:

- I've try to switch the connection type from NAT to bridge without any improvement
- All W7 settings are by default
- The network is marked as `Home`
- I use Avast on W7 & my mac
- Here's the [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3uzsu135t9ym3vb/dd_vs_enterprise_20160826110947.log?dl=0) to the full log
- [image]

Where should I dig to fix this?

Comment: Did you force all the updates?

Comment: @MartinDelille How do I force the updates...?

Comment: Go to update and make sure there is no update available

Comment: Sometimes available update are not  shown up immediately.